# NSSortDescriptor priorities

Tags: iphone, core-data, nssortdescriptor

I use NSSortDescriptor to sort contacts with firstName, but if the first name is nil, the sort it will be wrong.

if i have:

> contact 1: Firstname = BAAAA and LastName = XXXXXX
>
> contact 2:  Firstname = nil and LastName = AAAAAA

the sort it will be like this.

1- AAAAAAA

2- BAAAA XXXXXX

so i need to know if exist a solution to make priorities between Firstname and LastName.

if  `Firstname ==nil` so take LastName

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sorted = [contatcs sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor1, descriptor2]];
```

the order of the descriptors in the array determines priority. For a core data query it would be something like

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Contact" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

[request setSortDescriptors:@[descriptor1, descriptor2]];

NSError *error;
NSArray *array = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (array == nil)
{
    // Deal with error...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.
But, how i can do it if i want  to create a fetch request (core data) with NSSortDescriptors.
This is an Array sort not a fetch request.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `NSSortDescriptor` and override the `compareObject:toObject:` method:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareObject:(id)object1 toObject:(id)object2 {
    NSString *firstName1 = [object1 valueForKey:@"firstName"];
    NSString *lastName1 = [object1 valueForKey:@"lastName"];

    NSString *firstName2 = [object2 valueForKey:@"firstName"];
    NSString *lastName2 = [object2 valueForKey:@"lastName"];

    if(firstName1 == nil || firstName2 == nil) {
        return [lastName1 compare:lastName2];
    }

    return [firstName1 compare:firstName2];
}
```